# How to make ttk use OS theme?

Tags: ubuntu, tkinter, themes, ttk, python-3.7

I'm running python 3.7 on kubuntu with the Workspace Theme 'Breeze Dark'. The tk widgets in my application adopt the OS's theme correctly but ttk widgets use something else.

Is there a way to get my ttk widgets to use the OS's theme?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("ttk vs tk widget example")
        # tk example gui
        tk_frame = tk.Frame(master)
        tk_frame.pack()

        self.tk_label = tk.Label(tk_frame, text="tk label:")
        self.var1 = tk.StringVar(value="tk entry")
        self.tk_entry = tk.Entry(tk_frame, textvariable=self.var1)
        self.tk_quit_button = tk.Button(tk_frame,
                                        text="Quit", width=20,
                                        command=tk_frame.quit)
        self.tk_button = tk.Button(tk_frame,
                                   text="tk button", width=20)
        self.tk_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.tk_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.tk_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        self.tk_quit_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')

        separator = tk.Frame(height=2, bd=1, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        separator.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=5, pady=15)

        # ttk example gui
        ttk_frame = ttk.Frame(master)
        ttk_frame.pack()

        self.ttk_label = ttk.Label(ttk_frame, text="ttk label:")
        self.var2 = tk.StringVar(value="ttk entry")
        self.ttk_entry = ttk.Entry(ttk_frame, textvariable=self.var2)
        self.ttk_quit_button = ttk.Button(ttk_frame,
                                          text="Quit", width=20,
                                          command=ttk_frame.quit)
        self.ttk_button = ttk.Button(ttk_frame,
                                     text="ttk button", width=20)
        self.ttk_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.ttk_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.ttk_button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='e')
        self.ttk_quit_button.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='e')


root = tk.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Example of the ttk vs tk widgets:

[image: Example of ttk vs tk]

EDIT:
So it's not a real fix but I can set the colors to be correct with:

```
tk_bg = self.tk_label.cget("background")
tk_fg = self.tk_label.cget("foreground")

self.ttk_label = ttk.Label(ttk_frame, text="ttk label:", 
                           background=tk_bg, foreground=tk_fg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using XFCE desktop environment and even the tk widgets do not adapt to the theme I use which is not so surprising because XFCE is based on GTK GUI Toolkit so there is no reason for a GTK theme to influence a Tk theme.

So you will need to change the theme of the GUI manually and
the only way to set the colors of `ttk` widgets is through a `ttk.Style`:

```
tk_bg = self.tk_label.cget("background")
tk_fg = self.tk_label.cget("foreground")
tk_entrybg = self.tk_entry.cget("background")

style = ttk.Style(master)
style.configure('TFrame', background=tk_bg)
style.configure('TLabel', background=tk_bg, foreground=tk_fg)
style.configure('TButton', background=tk_bg, foreground=tk_fg)
style.configure('TEntry', background=tk_bg, fieldbackground=tk_entrybg, foreground=tk_fg)
```

All ttk widgets are associated to a style (usually 'T + widget name', except for the `Treeview` for which there is no extra 'T'). And those styles are defined by the ttk theme you use. You can change theme with `style.theme_use(<theme name>)` and you can get the available themes with `style.theme_names()`.